# ( goto was unexpected this time error

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, syntax, goto

My code below is throwing errors. Please help. I am new to batch file scripts. It is showing syntax error and "goto was unexpected this time" error.
My motive is to create a batch file which will accept a parameter from user. Based on that parameter, it will perform the tasks. Like if input is sql, it will execute an sql script. If input is foldercreation, it will create a new folder.

```
@echo off
cls

set /p FileType=Type of file :
if "%FileType%==SQL" (goto sql)
if "%FileType%==TXT" (goto text)
if "%FileType%==BAT" (goto bat)
if "%FileType%==FolderCreation" (goto FolderCreation)
if "%FileType%==FTP" (goto ftp)


:sql
set /p SName=Server Name :
set /p DbName=Database Name :
if exist _Deploy.txt del _Deploy.txt
@echo on
sqlcmd -S %SName% -E -d %DbName% -I -i "D:\Script\Execute_Script.sql" >>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
@notepad _Deploy.txt
exit /b

:text
if exist _Deploy.txt
@echo on
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\test1.txt" "D:\artifacts\Art2\">>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
@notepad _Deploy.txt
exit /b

:bat
if exist _Deploy.txt
@echo on
call testbatchcreatefolder.bat>>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
@notepad _Deploy.txt
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\testbatchcreatefolder.bat" "D:\artifacts\Art2\"
exit /b

:FolderCreation
set /p Mypath=Path please :
set /p Myfoldername=folder name :
set folder_path=%Mypath%\%Myfoldername%
md "%folder_path%"
exit /b

:FTP
if exist _Deploy.txt
@echo on
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\test2.txt" "D:\artifacts\Art2\">>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
@notepad _Deploy.txt
exit /b

pause

set /p delExit=Press the ENTER key to exit...:
:end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "%FileType%==SQL" (goto sql)
   ^...............^ = one string
```

So the previous code is equivalent to

```
if "this is not valid" (goto sql)
```

In an `if` command you need a condition. If it needs to compare two strings it should be

```
if "%FileType%"=="SQL" (goto sql)
   ^..........^  ^...^
```

When the parser replaces the variable reference with its value you end with one quoted string in each side of the `==` operator

This change should be made in all the similar lines.

Also, the lines

```
if exist _Deploy.txt
```

are missing the command part. If the intention is to execute the block of code following the `if`, then it should be

```
if exist _Deploy.txt (
    here the code to execute if the file exist
)
```

Comment: aah.Yes. Will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks..but after making the change , still i m getting the syntax of the command is incorrect error. What shall i do now?

Comment: @Meen, see updated answer. Check all your `if` conditions are ok. If you still have problems, please, remove `echo off` and see where the problem raises.

Comment: I guess I have found the problem...But still not the solution...:( the problem with the code is that the batch is not executing all the code of a SUb...I mean when I tried using onlt 1 line in the subs, they work fine..biut not the multi line subs

Comment: set /p FileType=Type of file :
if %FileType%==SQL goto sql
if %FileType%==TXT goto TEXT
if %FileType%==BAT goto bat
if %FileType%==FolderCreation goto FolderCreation
if %FileType%==FTP goto ftp
:TEXT
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\test1.txt" "D:\artifacts\Art2\">>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
exit /b
:FTP
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\test2.txt" "D:\artifacts\Art2\">>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
exit /b
:bat
call testbatchcreatefolder.bat>>_Deploy.txt 2>&1
move /-y "D:\artifacts\Art1\testbatchcreatefolder.bat" "D:\artifacts\Art2\"
exit /b

Comment: @Meen, and, what is the problem?

Comment: @MCND The problem is that the batch is only executing the first statement in the sub and not the whole block,